# A direct proof of the Vandermonde decomposition of a nonsingular Hankel matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, control-theory, hankel-matrices

I have been doggedly searching for a direct proof of the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1:** Let $H$ be a complex nonsingular $n\times n$ Hankel matrix. Then $H$ can be factorized $H = V^\top DV$ where $V$ is a complex $n\times n$ Vandermonde matrix and $D$ is a complex $n\times n$ diagonal matrix.

There exist *numerous* references stating that this result is well known either without proof or with a citation to one of the references below which I have found insufficient for one reason or another. Here is an abbreviated summary of my research:

- References (e.g., [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=4931052494945006421&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en), [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=13717560651449989575&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en), and [here](https://books.google.com/books/about/Special_Matrices_and_Their_Applications.html?id=SwzDAgAAQBAJ)) that are unavailable to me or in Russian
- References (e.g., [here](https://calhoun.nps.edu/handle/10945/30054), [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.332&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959290420F)) for a *confluent* Vandermonde decomposition of a rank-deficient finite and/or finite-rank infinite Hankel matrices: These do no prove the theorem I am after since the Vandermonde decomposition involves *confluent* Vandermonde matrices.
- References for a Vandermonde decomposition of [positive semidefinite](https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-2) or [positive definite](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002110050027) Hankel matrix: These don't address the case of a general square Hankel matrix.
- References ([here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-6241-7), [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-7643-8996-3), and [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/100800300)) where the theorem is proven as a corollary of a rather length theory: these results do prove the theorem that I want. However, the result follows as a corollary of several pages of a lengthy theory drawing connections to other structured matrices, polynomials, and rational functions. It seems like this basic and essential fact should have a more direct proof.

I am looking for as simple and direct a proof of Theorem 1 as possible, a reference to one in the literature, or some insight as to why a simple proof does not exist. Below the fold, I have outlined my attempt to provide such a proof.

---

**My Attempt**

Consider the entries of the Hankel matrix

$$
H = \begin{bmatrix} h_0 & h_1 & \cdots & h_{n-1} \\
h_1 & h_2 & \cdots & h_{n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
h_{n-1} & h_n & \cdots & h_{2n-2} \end{bmatrix}.
$$

The Vandermonde decomposition in Theorem 1 is equivalent to finding a representation of the sequence $(h_k)_{0\le k\le 2n-2}$ of the following form:

$$
h_k = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j z_j^k, \quad k = 0,1,2,\ldots,2n-2. \tag{$\star$}
$$

Observe that the sequence  $(h_k)_{0\le k\le 2n-2}$ has *fewer* parameters than the parametrization ($\star$). To rectify this, add $h_{2n-1}$, value to be set later, to the end of the sequence and require it to obey the parametrization ($\star$) for $k=2n-1$.

We seek to identify the poles $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ by [Prony's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prony%27s_method). The key observation is a sequence of the form ($\star$) is a solution to an order-$n$ difference equation:

$$
h_{n+k} = c_{n-1} h_{k+(n-1)} + \cdots + c_0 h_k.
$$

We find the difference equation coefficients $c_0,\ldots,c_{n-1}$ by solving the following linear system of equations

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
h_n \\ h_{n+1} \\ \vdots \\ h_{2n-1}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} h_0 & h_1 & \cdots & h_{n-1} \\
h_1 & h_2 & \cdots & h_{n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
h_{n-1} & h_n & \cdots & h_{2n-2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_0 \\ c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The matrix in this equation is precisely the matrix $H$ which we know to be nonzero. Thus, this equation has a unique solution $c_0,\ldots,c_{n-1}$. Provided the characteristic equation

$$
z^n - c_{n-1}z^{n-1} - \cdots - c_0z^0 = 0 \quad \text{has distinct roots} \quad z_1,\ldots,z_n, \tag{$\dagger$}
$$

there exist coefficients $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ such that ($\star$) holds. The Vandermonde decomposition is proven under the assumption ($\dagger$).

The Vandermonde decomposition thus rests on choosing $h_{2n-1}$ such that ($\dagger$) holds. Since $h_{2n-1}$ is arbitrary, the polynomial in ($\dagger$) can be chosen to be any polynomial of the form

$$
f(z) = g(z) + \alpha h(z)
$$

where

$$
g(z) = z^n - d_{n-1} z^{n-1} - \cdots - d_0 z^0, \quad h(z) = -e_{n-1} z^{n-1} - \cdots - e_0 z^0 \tag{$\blacktriangle$}
$$

with $d_0,\ldots,d_{n-1}$ and $e_0,\ldots,e_{n-1}$ the solutions of

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
h_n \\ h_{n+1} \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} = H \begin{bmatrix} d_0 \\ d_1 \\ \vdots \\ d_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ h_{2n-1}
\end{bmatrix} = H \begin{bmatrix} e_0 \\ e_1 \\ \vdots \\ e_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

To this end, we have a helpful lemma (see, e.g., [Lemma 7.7](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-7643-8996-3)):

> **Lemma 2.** *If any polynomials $g$ and $h$ are coprime*, then $g - \alpha h$ has simple roots except for finitely many values $\alpha$.

Thus, Theorem 1 would be proven if I could show that $g$ and $h$ as defined in ($\blacktriangle$) are coprime.

Comment: Unless I've missed something, one proof for this result is [given here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.1833&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: @BenGrossmann I don't believe that Theorem 1 is proven in the cited article. This article focuses on the _confluent_ Vandermonde decomposition of infinite Hankel matrices. They address the square nonsingular case at the bottom of page 7. However, as far as I can tell, they do not prove the existence of a $h_{2n-1}$ such that ($\dagger$) has simple roots. As such, they only prove the existence of a _confluent_ Vandermonde decomposition of a nonsingular Hankel matrix.

Comment: $(\dagger)$ must be $\ldots\;=0$, right?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Thanks for the correction. Fixed